# How to. I want a name that is in an array. ReactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to. I want a name that is in an array.I tried to do it like this. addedItems.data.name But it didn't work

### this is array addedItems

```
onFinish = async(values) => {
    console.log(values)
    const { addedItems, total } = this.state;
    console.log(addedItems.data.name);
}
```

### Values that are in addedItems

[image]

Comment: See [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: This is not a reactjs specific question. You're simply asking how to do normal javascript array and object data lookups. You want `addedItems[0].name`

Comment: Arrays use indexes so access index before property name `addedItems.data[0].name`

Comment: like everyone already said addedItems[0].name

Comment: This is just one information, I want it to show all I have.